# How to animate up UITableView when Keyboard pops up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with 10 rows.  Each cell has a `UITextField` in it.

The problem is, when I click a `UITextField` in a cell at the bottom, the keyboard pops up and blocks the cell.  How can I deal with this? Do I need to animate the tableview up or something?

Updated Code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.vitalsTableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,200,0);
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.vitalsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.vitalsTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Check [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) for keyboard [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html). I published an [example code.](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/KeyboardScroll/KeyboardScroll)

Answer (score 5):

use `- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated` method of UITableView

example:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

will scroll your tableView to the lowermost possible offset that maintains the cell visible. If your cell does not have enough cells under, you can set a contentInset for your table to allow the scroll offset.

maybe your UITextField delegate is the table view controller. You can make the call on `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

In the case of the bottom cell:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    tableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,200,0);
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    tableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example on how to implement it in my scenario?

Comment: I did that and nothing happens when I click the UITextField in one of the bottom cells.  It is still covered by the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, that worked somewhat.  It now lets me scroll up when I click a UITextField so I can see the cell, but it doesn't scroll automatically, like it still covers the cells, but it at least lets me scroll the table so I can see it manually.  Is there any way I can fix that?  Do I have to do a  different `contentInset` for each row?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this same problem in iOS 7: I found that this problem was happening to me simply because I forgot to call the super class' implementation of `viewWillAppear:` in my own `viewWillAppear:` implementation. One line fixed the problem:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  // Do whatever you need to
}
```